# How can we merge an SWF video with any other type of video with PHP?

Tags: php, video, flash

I want to merge a video of any type into .SWF video using PHP. It should create a third file after merging both the files.

Comment: Then? How can it be achieved?

Comment: Using a command line tool like `ffmpeg` if that's available on your server

Comment: Can you provide an example for this please? Sample FFMPEG commands?

Comment: Not really - I would have to Google them, too - check out http://ffmpeg.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

**Joining two video files:**

```
ffmpeg -i input1.avi -same_quant intermediate1.mpg
ffmpeg -i input2.avi -same_quant intermediate2.mpg
cat intermediate1.mpg intermediate2.mpg > intermediate_all.mpg
ffmpeg -i intermediate_all.mpg -same_quant output.swf
```

See the relevant [link here](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-join-video-files_003f)!

Comment: Hi zuul, this command not work for me, i want to join flv files, and don't know how to do this.

Comment: @ime.devdesks You should place a question about your particular issue, but check the [ffmpeg documentation: Concatenating using raw audio and video](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#toc-Concatenating-using-raw-audio-and-video). Click that link, when the page loads, you should see that phrase, click over it to scroll down to an example concatenating flv files.

Comment: I asked my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985414/php-ffmpeg-joining-videos), please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you started
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992925/how-to-convert-a-video-to-swf

It is not that php can't do the work, just that it would be slow and you would probably have to write it yourself.  There may be utilizes (like FFMPEG, vlc) that could do the work but they are written in C/C++ most likely.  To use them you would probably have a longer running perl script call them and then update a database to let you know the job was done.

Comment: FFMPEG and VLC are C/C++